# how to find average of each column of a datatable using c#

Tags: linq

I have a .csv file containing names, roll, subjects correspondingly.I parsed it into a datatable and I calculated the highest mark of each subject. All i want to calculate is the average of each Subject. Can anyone help me with this !!!!!

This was my output.

Highest mark for ComputerScience:

```
    Name : Manoj
    Roll Number : 1212334556
    Mark : 94
```

Highest Mark for Biology:

```
    Name : Sandeep
    Roll Number : 1223456477
    Mark : 90
```

Highest Mark for Commerce:

```
    Name : BarathRam
    Roll Number : 1212345664
    Mark : 97
```

And csv file contains Names,Rollno, Computer, Biology, Commerce.

Now all i need to get is the average of each subject

My code:

```
    static DataTable table;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\GOPINATH\Desktop\stud1.csv");
        string line = r.ReadLine(); //reads first line - column header
        string[] part = line.Split(','); //splits the line by comma
        createDataTable(part);
        //copy from CSV to DataTable<String,String,int,int,int>
        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            try
            {
                part = line.Split(',');
                table.Rows.Add(part[0], part[1], Convert.ToInt32(part[2]), Convert.ToInt32(part[3]), Convert.ToInt32(part[4]));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);   
            }
        }
        r.Close();

        int mark1_index = 0, mark2_index = 0, mark3_index = 0; //initailize index value 0 for highest marks 

        //finding the index of the highest mark for each subject
        for(int i=0 ; i<table.Rows.Count ; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][2]) > Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[mark1_index][2])) //subject1
            {
                mark1_index = i;
            }

            if (Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][3]) > Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[mark2_index][3])) //subject2
            {
                mark2_index = i;
            }

            if (Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][4]) > Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[mark3_index][4])) //subject3
            {
                mark3_index = i;
            }
        }

        printmark(table,mark1_index, 2);
        printmark(table,mark2_index, 3);
        printmark(table,mark3_index, 4);

        Console.Read();

    }
    public static void createDataTable(string[] columnName)
    {
        //create DataTable<String,String,int,int,int>
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add(columnName[0], typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add(columnName[1], typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add(columnName[2], typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add(columnName[3], typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add(columnName[4], typeof(int));     
    }
    public static void printmark(DataTable t, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Highest mark for " + t.Columns[columnIndex].ColumnName + ":");
        Console.WriteLine("\tName: " + (string)t.Rows[rowIndex][0]);
        Console.WriteLine("\tRole Number: " + (string)t.Rows[rowIndex][1]);
        Console.WriteLine("\tMark: " + (int)t.Rows[rowIndex][columnIndex]);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use *Linq* and do this.

```
DataTable t;
var average = t.AsEnumerable().Average(x=> x.Field<int>("columnname"));
```

Comment: You want to find average for each column, right? this query calculates average for a given `columnname`

Comment: !! Can you be more specific. As I'm a beginner in c# , I cannot find the region where i need to insert this query. If possible can you send your query in my code. As i find it difficult to implement. I would start moving on with next one. Thanks !!

Comment: You can just send me the region where i need to insert your query into my code. It would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
var result=table.AsEnumerable()
   .GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("Subject"))
   .Select(x=>new 
     {
       Subject=x.Key,
       Average=x.Average(x=> x.Field<int>("Mark"));
     }).ToList();
```

In order to calculate the average mark by Subject, first you need to groupby Subject then calculate the average for each group.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! @Bumb can you send me your query along with my code.. I find it little difficult to insert your query into my code. It shows error for me <Regards-cJ>

Comment: @cjgeez I did not check your code!, I assume that you were able to read the file and generate the `DataTable`. Once your `DataTable` is generated, and you have the Columns `"Subject"` and `"Mark"`, you can use my query to get an `anonymous` object with 2 props (`Subject` and `Average`).